# Adding an image over UIButton?

Tags: objective-c

I am having `UIButtons` that uses images .
Now i want to be able to set another `UIImage` above that button when it hit, and remove it when you hit it again .

Some kind of a check mark for a list .

**EDIT:**

My images on buttons are images from phone memory. i cant just change the image to another, because the images was loaded from memory and its not external asset. so i need to put some fixed image above all buttons that are pushed .

1. should i add it as another `UIButton` over the previous ?
2. should i put it as a `UIImage` above it-and the `UIButton` will still get touches ?

whats the best way ?
Thnank.

```
UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+10, row*100+10, 92, 92); // distnace related to scroller(not view)
        [button setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Or you could change button's image..

Comment: see my edit its not  the case

Comment: What do you mean "images from phone memory". If you have UIImage object, it does not matter how you instantiated, you can use it as any other UIImage

Comment: no. because i can't change them again and again. the images where loaded from memory and set to buttons. i cant load them again, because it takes time. they are not there for my free usage -like external asset. they are loaded from phone .

Comment: what i mean, is that there is only one chance for each button to retrieve the image (from assetsLibrary), later i dont have the link to them anymore, so when the button is highlighted and if later its back to the original state- he will not have that original image again anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. you could do it with multiple options:
1. Add `UIImageView` above your button and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the image view with method to remove it on second click.
2. You could use also button's backgroundColor with pattern image that fits exactly to your button (to avoid repeats).
3. Use layers with `CGImageRef`

Comment: My answer is just an example to @Vinzzz answer

Comment: can i do that- but on the highlight image set 2 images: the original one and the other one above it? if yes , whats the syntax for that ?

Comment: Highlight should be preserved for "TouchDown" event. It's a bad practice to do hacks on it.

Comment: @user1994291: can't you 'merge' original image + image above ? (if they're preloaded in the app), If you want to display at same time more images than UIButton provides - which is 1 image / button state - then you're right : you have to use another imageView

Comment: @pbibergal thanks a lot. you got me. so if i want to do number2- if the background is in the size of the image-will it cover it ? (thats what i need).

Comment: The button.imageView will cover the button.backgroundColor, so you'll need to set default image as the background and the additional that you want to show and hide, as button.imageView.

Comment: what? i don't get it . if i set to the button a new background- the checked image, i dont see the original button-image..

Comment: What is original button image?

Comment: thanks. at the end i have merged 2 images to 1 and set the background of each button . . .

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the APIs UIButton offers : `setImage:forState:` with UIControlStateSelected (the state the button should get once you've hit it once) / UIControlStateNormal.
Button can be `highlighted`or `selected`. Highlighted is when you're pushing it, (goes away as soon as touches stop), while selected is set to YES after 1st touch, and back to NO on second.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have custom button, the best solution is to change image of the button depending on the state of a checkbox you have (you mentioned that the idea is to create something like checkbox button).

There is a method in UIButton class named "setImage:forState:". You can change the image inside the button using mentioned method.
See more info [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Example how I see the code (you can see it another way):

```
// bool property
@property (assign) BOOL isChecked;
....
// custom button
UIButton *theCheckboxButton = ;
[theCheckboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theCheckboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[theCheckboxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButtonAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
// handler
- (void)checkBoxButtonAction:(UIButton *)aCheckBox
{
    self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;
    [aCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:(self.isChecked ? @"Checked" : @"Unchecked")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theCheckboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:(self.isChecked ? @"Unchecked" : @"Checked")] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
// images from not external resources
@property (strong) UIImage *checkedImage;
@property (strong) UIImage *uncheckedImage;
// bool property
@property (assign) BOOL isChecked;
...
// custom button
UIButton *theCheckboxButton = ;
[theCheckboxButton setImage:self.uncheckedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theCheckboxButton setImage:self.checkedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[theCheckboxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButtonAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
// handler
- (void)checkBoxButtonAction:(UIButton *)aCheckBox
{
    self.isChecked = !self.isChecked;
    [aCheckBox setImage:self.isChecked ? self.checkedImage : self.uncheckedImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [theCheckboxButton setImage:(self.isChecked ? self.uncheckedImage : self.checkedImage) forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

Comment: Your handler is not optimal.. There is no need again to set image for selected state.Only change the button state - selected | not selected.

Comment: I dont get your answer. now if the user will tap on the button, he will not see the original image anymore, but ONLY the new image. i wanted that when you push a button, you see its image and above it another image with a checked. its not what your code is do no ??